# Compress Arraylist or passing arraylist with objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have application with google map, because googlemaps not provide api to create routes on map in Android, i'm using WebApi to get routes.
I store route in ArrayList, and pass then throught Intent into my activity where drow a route. If LatLng objects less then 2000 it works nice, else if it more then 2000 objects then i have Java Binder Exception, maybe Intent have limit size. 
To handle situation with more then 2000 objects i save LatLng latitude and longitude to file and pass only path, then in activity i load file. But this files very big ~ 0.5-3 mB. 
How i can solve my problem, or how i can compress my arraylist with double values?

Comment: Can you show us a bit of code or an object diagram with a sample of the data in the arraylist? its hard to tell you what to do when we cant see what you have done already. Thanks.

Comment: In arraylist only objects LatLng, they have only two fields(double) - latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts

- Don't use an object to encapsulate lat/long as that has additional overhead. Use a data structure that is more concise such as an array of Doubles or a geohash of the lat/long coordinates
- Compress the output as another answer suggested
- A more advanced option could be to use a trie to encode the list of geohashs. Given that a route is going to consist of numerous coordinates very close to each other the 'compression' is likely to be quite high.

Answer (score 0):

You could compress your data to an ZipOutputStream and pass this as raw bytes or use the way over a ZipFile. Compression should be quite good, if values ocure more often.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't waste space when writing the data. Don't use text/ASCII/XML data structures/files for storing the data.

Use `DataOutputStream` and `writeDouble(..)` method for writing the data (result: 8 byte per double value). Alternatively you could convert the double values to float and write them via `writeFloat(..)` - that would halve the data to be written. Usually for displaying points on a map a float would still be precise enough.

Reading works of course just the other way round using `DataInputStream`.

Compression would also be an option but better to minimize the data to be written first as compression can take much CPU resources, meaning it consumes power and time.

Comment: Oh, i save my doubles into the file as Strings, and load them as Strings and convert to double :(

Comment: That is nearly the worst you can do if you want to minimize the saved size.